# Background image transition is not working on mozilla

Tags: javascript, css, mozilla

Background image transition is not working on mozilla
it is working fine on chrome

```css
    .mobile_view {
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.and_bg {
    background-image: url("../img/app_bg3.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 575px;
    width: 286px; 
}
.ios_bg {
    background-image: url("../img/app_bg2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 575px;
    width: 286px; 
}
```

Comment: Which versions of Chrome and Mozilla are you using? Also, could you please post your HTML code?

Comment: <div class="mobile_view" ng-class="phone == 'ANDROID' ? 'and_bg' : 'ios_bg'">
</div>

Im using angular